# I want to expand.grid from each row of a matrix when the matrix could have variable number of rows

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

```html
myMatrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),2,3, byrow=T) # line 1

exp.myMatrix <- function(myMatrix) { # line 2
  for (rownum in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) assign(paste("R",rownum, sep=""), myMatrix[rownum,]) # line 3
  Combinations <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(ls(pattern='^R\\d$'), get)) # line 4
  rm(list=ls(pattern='^R\\d$')) # line 5
  return(Combinations) # line 6
} # line 7

Combinations <- exp.myMatrix(myMatrix) # line 8
```

The above code gives error: "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'R1' not found".

However, when I do not use the function and run only lines 1, 3, 4, 5, I do not get any error. But I need to pass myMatrix through a function as the matrix would have variable number of rows. Also note that I need to run line 5 as I need to clear the variables for the next matrix which could have lesser number of rows than the previous one.

Comment: this insanely complicated for something simple.... using `R` this way with assign/get is poor coding since it results in playing with envrionment to dump variable in the global envir ...must be avoided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rather use:

```
do.call(expand.grid, split(myMatrix, rep(1:nrow(myMatrix), ncol(myMatrix))))

#  1 2
#1 1 4
#2 2 4
#3 3 4
#4 1 5
#5 2 5
#6 3 5
#7 1 6
#8 2 6
#9 3 6
```